# How is the right way to implement login on CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller

I'm practicing Codeigniter framework using a small project from my friends. Each pages need to load layout view and content view separately. The layout show users login info (logged or not, name, picture, etc.). The question is, how to show login info for each action efficiently? Most of the action will load the layout view, so i need to do that right.

I do implement a helper to get user model, but is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following method:-

**In one separate model constructor function check the login details**

```
class Auth extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct(){

        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->model('loginModel');

        $this->load->library('session');

        if(!$this->loginModel->isLogin()){

            $this->session->sess_destroy();

            redirect('index.php/auth/login','refresh');

            exit;

        }

    }
}
```

**Then in required controllers include the model in the controller constructor function**

```
class Main extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();      
        $this->load->model('auth');
    }

}
```

**No need to check all the controller action's if you added in the controller constructor it will check for all the actions**

Comment: Then, how do i retrieve user information from view, something like Fullname or Picture Link? Do I need to send login information from all actions on all controllers through $this->load->view('view/example', [something here]) ?

Comment: No, the common header, footer view also you can load in constructor function

Comment: CI is using MVC architecture, then is that okay to load view from Model?

Comment: No, load it in controller constructor function.

Comment: Ok, copy that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Frist Create Login Controller, in that controller

- Ask User to login
- Check if password is correct. If yes, set session value (say user_id) & redirect to User Controller.

Second Create User Controller, in that controller's constructor function

- Check Session user_id exist or not. If no, redirect to login.

It is best to check at constructor because it will check for all the methods in that controller.

Hope it helps.